# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget when I try to make a drawer menu

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer

i check this doc first:
https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/common-errors#incorrect-use-of-parentdata-widget
and know the usually scenario is when use Expanded or some widgets under the wrong parent widget.
but that's not what I do.

I actually tried to make a muti-level menu like this

[image]

and my drawer code is like this
drawer.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDrawer({super.key});


  @override
  State<MyDrawer> createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> {
  bool showHistory = false;
  bool showConfig = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/images/logo.svg',
                ),
               
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/images/speedometer.svg',
            ),
            title: const Text('Dashboard'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/images/chemical_bottles.svg',
            ),
            title: const Text('Jobs'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/jobs');
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/images/box.svg',
            ),
            title: const Text('History'),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                showHistory = !showHistory;
              });
            },
          ),
          if (showHistory) ...[
            ListTile(
              leading: const Spacer(),
              title: const Text('Batches'),
              onTap: () {
                // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/history');
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: const Spacer(),
              title: const Text('Shipments'),
              onTap: () {
                // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/history');
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: const Spacer(),
              title: const Text('Supplier Invoices'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/supplierivcs');
              },
            ),
          ],
          ListTile(
            leading: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/images/cog.svg',
            ),
            title: const Text('Configurations'),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                showConfig = !showConfig;
              });
            },
          ),
          if (showConfig) ...[
            ListTile(
              leading: const Spacer(),
              title: const Text('Currency'),
              onTap: () {
                // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/history');
              },
            )
          ]
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

if I clicked on the first level menu(like histroy in the pic), try to show those second level ,this error will occur

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong to use

```
leading: const Spacer(),
```

A spacer is literally just an `Expanded` without children. I'm not sure what you want but you could just leave out the `leading` or put a `SizedBox` with some width there

Comment: got it, I just want the second level all have indent.ok add SizedBox make it work, thanks